# Why did I obtain wrong answer when using "=="?

Tags: r

If I type:

```
x<-seq(0,20,.05)
x[30]
x[30]==1.45
```

Why do I obtain a `False` from the last line of code? What did I do wrong here?

Comment: x[30] is `14.5` not `1.45`. I dint down-vote, but I think you should delete this question.

Comment: Yes I made a typo in my question I have now corrected. You should read x<-seq(0,20,.05)

Comment: This is due to [**floating point inaccuracy**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Do this: `x <- seq(0, 20, 0.5); sprintf("%.20f", x[30])` and now this: `x <- seq(0, 20, 0.05); sprintf("%.20f", x[30])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked a million times, albeit in different forms. This is due to [**floating point inaccuracy**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Also [**here's another link**](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/floatingpoint-errors-explained.html) on floating point errors you may want to catch up on!

Try this to first see what's going on:

```
x <- seq(0, 20, 0.5)
sprintf("%.20f", x[30]) # convert value to string with 20 decimal places
# [1] "14.50000000000000000000"
x[30] == 14.5
# [1] TRUE
```

All is well so far. Now, try this:

```
x <- seq(0, 20, 0.05)
sprintf("%.20f", x[30]) # convert value to string with 20 decimal places
# [1] "1.45000000000000017764"
x[30] == 1.45
# [1] FALSE
```

You can see that the machine is able to *accurately* represent this number only up to certain digits. Here, up to 15 digits or so. So, by directly comparing the results, you get of course a FALSE. Instead what you could do is to use `all.equal` which has a parameter for *tolerance* which equals `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`. On my machine this evaluates to `1.490116e-08`. This means if the absolute difference between the numbers `x[30]`  and `1.45...` is < this threshold, then `all.equal` evaluates this to TRUE.

```
all.equal(x[30], 1.45)
[1] TRUE
```

Another way of doing this is to explicitly check with a specific threshold (as [@eddi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324981/why-i-obtain-wrong-answer-when-using/16325091#16325091) shows it).

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the fact that these are `double`'s, and the correct way of comparing `double`'s in any language is to do something like:

```
abs(x[30] - 1.45) < 1e-8   # or whatever precision you think is appropriate
```